# T SQL Export to XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm using MS SQL Server 2016 SP2.

I have a table that contains two columns like this:

```
Filename                      XML
---------                     --------------------
c:\myfolder\test.xml          <?xml version blah blah blah 
c:\myfolder\test2.xml         <?xml version blah blah blah
c:\myfolder\test3.xml         <?xml version blah blah blah
```

Using SQL I want to export the XML in the `XML` column and create the file from the `Filename` column. I have tried using a cursor and BCP as shown below, but I keep getting the message:

> Copy direction must be either 'in', 'out' or 'format'. usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile

This is my SQL - where am I going wrong?

Thanks for any help.

```
  DECLARE @name VARCHAR(MAX)
  DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
      SELECT [Filename] FROM Instances

  OPEN db_cursor

  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @NAME

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp -S xxxxxxx -d xxxxxxxxx "SELECT [XML] FROM Instances WHERE [Filename] = @NAME" -o @NAME -T -c -t -x'

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @NAME
  END

 CLOSE db_cursor
 DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: I feel like this would be easier with SSIS. You could use a For Each Loop on the dataset returned from your table, and easily the use a Data Flow Task to write out the text files to a flat file source with a variable as the path.

Comment: Tried SSIS but it messes up the format of the XML as there is no output to XML out of the box

Comment: @Michael if you uxed FOR XML and a flat file target it won't mess up anything. As for your code, why are you using *SQL* to execute shell commands? Shell commands aren't *SQL* so they don't know anything about SQL variables. That `@Name` string is just a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> copy direction must be either 'in', 'out' or 'format'. usage: bcp
>   {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile

Because of:

- Missing `queryout`
- Source query to be stated just after BCP and other switches to be listed after the query
- Additionaly, the original code has a wrong injection of `@Name` variable into a dynamic sql.

Adjusted `xp_cmdshell` command:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT CAST([XML] as XML) FROM Instances WHERE [Filename] = '+@NAME+'"  queryout "'+@NAME+'" -S"xxxxxxx" -d"xxxxxxxxx" -c -T'
```

If the outgoing file expected to be in a UNICODE,  this extra switch: `-w` can be added

Comment: The significant change in this answer is concatenating `@NAME` instead of just including it in the shell command

Comment: @Michael, I have tested on my side and adjusted the answer, the query is to be the first after `bcp` and only then other switches

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the reason was actually in the wrong order. The right and working one is: `bcp.exe "query" queryout "C:\somewhere" -list_of_arguments`

Comment: I changed order but now receive the error 'Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file'

Comment: @Michael, can be related to permissions of the SQL Service account. Is it has enough permissions to read/write/create files? will this work: EXEC `xp_cmdshell 'MKDIR "C:\Somewhere"'` where somewhere is your full path to a place of xml files to be stored

Comment: @Alexander_Volok you are correct - it is now working!